From-to construction
Please help me parse this sentence. I'm not asking for proofreading; I'm looking at grammatical construction concerning range. I say it's a run-on and false range (I am not including the misplaced apostrophe). At most, the sentence is cumbersome due to the participial modifiers, but I want to ensure I'm not missing anything other than being picky. My sources only send me discussions of range and devices, but I cannot locate set rules for constructing ranges. If it's correct, I stand corrected!
"Individualism holds a special place in America, from the first beginnings of the pilgrims and colonists wanting a fresh start and fleeing towards the new world with hopes of a new beginning and freedom from corrupt monarchies that restricted individual’s room for growth, to today as we see immigrants coming over from lands that have been torn apart with war, government, etc. that impede the community and the individual as a whole."

So many opportunities for improvement.

Aside from the misplaced apostrophe in "individual's," the sentence is grammatically correct. I'm not sure why one would write a sentence with that level of syntactic complexity, but it isn't ungrammatical.
That said, there are a couple of non-grammar-related issues here:
First, consider the phrase "lands that have been torn apart with war, government, etc." I'm not sure how a land can be "torn apart with government," but that seems to be the only logical reading of that phrase.
Secondly, in "the community and the individual as a whole," I suspect that the order has been reversed; it makes a lot more sense to say "the individual and the community as a whole."
